# How to Restrict access to phone's basic features, no one can uninstall my app, complete lock down?

Tags: java, android, android-ndk

Recently my employer asked me to build an app which is to be deployed on the field (for field workers) having features such as:
-when the phone starts the app should automatically fire up and no one is able to make use of other phone's features such as calling, texting etc.

Also, the app should be as such that it cannot be uninstalled.
Imagine a complete restricted access to phone's features except my app; a total lock down situation?

So, how really can I go about this? Will I need to build a whole new custom ROM loaded with my app? Or will I have to make use of app's "permissions" to lock down the system? Which is better?

Where should I start?
My app has to make use of SQLite, GPS, Wifi/2G/3G network and camera access.

Any advice would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U can create an application which will be listening for `Activity starting` event. When u catch this event u can start your own activity. This activity will suppliant uninstall activity. To catch event - use logcat reading

or

If your are going to launch your own android phone, put your application in the android source, like the other native applications like Myfiles, Gallery. and

> modify the source, so that in `Settings --> Manage Applications` there
>   is no entry for your application.

Comment: By listening to and using "Activity starting" event that would also make sure that the user is not able to open any other application (including the build-in ones such as dialer, manage applciations)? Is that correct? Also "modifying the source" I assume you're talking about modifying the custom ROM's source?

Comment: @quantumstates            yes

Comment: But wouldn't that create a bottle neck situation? Like starting an activity(my app) automatically over user-started another app's activity?

Comment: Marking yours as the Answer as its quite near to what I want to achieve. Thanks for the discussion..

Answer (score 0):

First of all I should say such a horrible plan

you can not prevent system to uninstall your application. According to your client's requirement you can only do one thing. That is to launch the application when the phone is started by using BOOT_COMPLETED intent filter

Comment: Well, BOOT_COMPLETED intent filter will only make my app to run just after the boot. But the user would be able to exit my app using the standard "back" button :D Anyhow, can I make sure that my app ignores that? That the user is not able to exit my app?

Comment: you can overwrite the backbutton to prevent user to stop your application. but user can always force stop your application from settings

Comment: but how can the user be able to access "phone's settings" if my app is starting up at the very boot up of the phone? Also, I can make sure that I can restart the phone/app in case of a crash/lockup with database backup and error logs being uploaded to a server.

Comment: Is it possible to override the home, search button as well?

Comment: Thanks for the discussion. Marked Ravindra's reply as the Answer as it was quite near to what I want to achieve.